# How reinstall a package using dpkg_package chef resource

Tags: chef-infra, dpkg

I am using chef's `dpkg_package` resource to install a deb package from a source file. My system creates test versions of the software all the time and I have cron job to run `chef-solo` to make sure I have latest version of the software. However, `dpkg_package` doesn't update/overwrite package files, if package is already installed. I tried to spoof `version` attribute of the `dpkg_package` but that didn't help either.

Is there a way to re-install a deb package (or force overwrite) using chef's `dpkg_package` resource?

Comment: Did you try `action :remove` and then another `action :install`?

Comment: I did not, as I am not sure if that would be a good idea to do it.

I tried using `options` by passing `--ovewrite` but that did not work. Upon going through chef source code, seems like installation process for `dpkg` is short circuited with package existence check

Comment: yes that makes sense it'd do that, it's trying to be idempotent. But try one resource that removes and another that installs, it should work.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I'm in a similar boat and looking at trying something like:
options '--force-downgrade'

Comment: I looked through source code and looks like `dpkg_package` doesn't support reinstall. Even trying `options` didn't work. 

I ended up using build timestamp in the package version